# How secure is facebook connect?

Tags: facebook, security

I am looking into using Facebook connect as a way for users to log in to my site.  However I've noticed that it doesn't use SSL. also I've noticed that doesn;t look like SSL is being used in the main facebook login area either.
My site holds sensitive info about the user and am concerned that Facebook connect could make this vulnerable. 
Am I right in thinking this?  I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really concern about this security issue, then simply just prompt for password (no need for username since you already know this user from FBC) like how Yahoo does.

It is just to confirm that the user is actually him/herself.